# Can't verify facebook callback url or verify token using python chalice

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-messenger-bot, chalice

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def webhook_verify():
    print('testing')
    # Get all query parameters from the GET request
    query_params = app.current_request.query_params

    # Log all parameter names and values
    logger.info('Query parameters received:')
    for param_name, param_value in query_params.items():
        print(f'{param_name}: {param_value}')

    hub_verify_token = query_params.get('hub.verify_token')
    hub_challenge = query_params.get('hub.challenge')

    if hub_verify_token == VERIFY_TOKEN:
        # Log a successful verification
        print('Webhook verification successful')
        return str(query_params.get("hub.challenge")), 200  # 200 OK
    
    # Log an unsuccessful verification
    print('Webhook verification failed: Wrong verify token')
    return {'error': 'Wrong verify token'}, 403  # 403 Forbidden
```

Here's the code that handles the webhook

And then I verify the callback url in the facebook developers page. It then says

```
The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.
```

But, when looking at the cloudwatch logs, it shows this:
[image: Logs showing that verification token is correct]

It shows that verification token is correct, and returns a 200 response. So, I'm confused why it shows there's an error on the facebook developer page

What I've tried:
Looking at other return response formats of other python facebook messenger repositories and following that format, but no luck.

Comment: You should be able to verify that you are getting the correct, expected response, by making such a GET request in your own browser. If that is not the case - fix your script; if it is - figure out why it apparently behaves differently, when requested by Facebook's servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
        return str(query_params.get("hub.challenge")), 200  # 200 OK
```

To

```
        return str(query_params.get("hub.challenge"))
```

Turns out, using chalice for facebook webhooks for 200 requests doesn't need to be stated. Works now after changing that